# Filter for rows with duplicate values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

**Tibble:**

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9),
              y = c(rep("condition_one", 5), rep("condition_two", 3)))
```

**Goal:**

I want to return rows of 'non-unique' values in `x` AND for `condition_one` in `y`. In this example it would be row 2 and 5 because the value 3 is not unique in `x` and `y` is `condition_one`.

What I first tried was using the `duplicated()` function from base R:

```
df %>% 
  filter(duplicated(.$x) & y == "condition_one")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      x y            
  <dbl> <chr>        
1     3 condition_one
```

Though it only returns the duplicated row and not the "original" one.
What would be a solution in this case that I can also include in a dplyr pipe chain?

**EDIT:**

I see that some answers still don't solve my problem and I think it's because I phrased my question badly:
In my filtered output, I only want rows where the value in `x` was not unique. But I want R to return ALL the non-unique rows, not only the one where the duplicate value first occured (which is happening with `duplicate()`).
On top of that, I want `y == "condition_one"`

Comment: You could do `df %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    filter(n() != 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get if you want to find duplicates in the universe where df$y meets "condition_one" or the opposite. I'll write both cases.

In base R:

Case 1: Find all duplicates and then find which ones meet condition.

```
all_duplicates <- df[duplicated(df$x) | duplicated(df$x, fromLast = TRUE), ]
your_condition <- all_duplicates[all_duplicates$y == "condition_one", ]
```

Case 2: Find which ones meet condition and then find duplicates there.

```
df_cond <- df[df$y == "condition_one", ]

all_duplicates <- df_cond[duplicated(df_cond$x) | duplicated(df_cond$x, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

Comment: This still only returns the duplicate value, not the "original" one.

Comment: My bad. It should work now. I forgot to add df$x and not just df

Comment: It still only returns the duplicate value for me

Comment: Oh ok, I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(y == "condition_one" & n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

#Results:
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x y            
  <dbl> <chr>        
1     2 condition_one
2     5 condition_one
```

Comment: This returns the values 2 and 5 in ```x```. Not the second and fifth row in ```x``` in which 3 is the duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(duplicated(cur_data()) & y == 'condition_one')
```

Comment: This only returns the first duplicate value in ```x```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out this package called `campfin` and it contains a function, `flag_dupes()` which does exactly what you want. In a nutshell, it adds a logical column it calls `dupe_flag` which you can use to filter out unique rows.